# Traveling with ESTA while having a F1 student visa

Tags: visas

I am a student in the US on a F1 student visa, but I am currently in Europe. I will start my master's at the end of August, which means I am receiving a new I-20 that only allows me to enter 30 days prior to the start date.

I need to be back in the US June 25th for holidays. Can I get in the US in a Visa Waiver, which allows me to enter the US on June 25th as planned (as a tourist) and 30 days before classes begin, I will fly home back to Europe. A couple of days later I can then fly back to the US with the new dates on my I-20 for the Fall semester.

Is this possible?

Comment: Note: ESTA is not a visa, but an authorization to board a plane or boat headed to the US. You would enter on the Visa Waiver Program, which, as the name indicates, is not  visa.

Comment: In theory it is possible (and you don't even need to go all the way home to reenter the US; you could go to Canada or Mexico or any other foreign territory), but I don't know how likely it is that you would be admitted on the VWP in these circumstances.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I visit the USA as a VWP tourist immediately prior to entry on non-tourist visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90068/can-i-visit-the-usa-as-a-vwp-tourist-immediately-prior-to-entry-on-non-tourist-v) and [Tourist to F1 change of status](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112405/tourist-to-f1-change-of-status-within-60-days/112410#112410)